# How to statically link a Chicken Scheme program that uses extensions?

Tags: scheme, static-linking, chicken-scheme

I have need to compile and **statically link** a Chicken program. I expect to use many extensions, most notably `http-client`.

I can compile the source with the following command:

```
csc -compile-syntax -static linux-setup.scm
```

or

```
csc -R http-client -compile-syntax -static linux-setup.scm
```

But when I run it, I get the following error:

```
Error: (require) cannot load extension: http-client

    Call history:

    ##sys#require           <--
```

I have also tried `(declare (uses http-client))` in the source, with no success:

```
linux-setup.o: In function `f_369':
/mnt/data/Documents/Programming/chicken-scheme/linux-setup/linux-setup.c:219:
 undefined reference to `C_http_2dclient_toplevel'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Error: shell command terminated with non-zero exit status 256: 'gcc' 'linux-setup.o'
 -o 'linux-setup' -L"/usr/lib"  -Wl,-R"/usr/lib" -static '/usr/lib/libchicken.a' -lm -ldl
```

Static linking is something I **need**. This is not an XY problem. I **need** my executables to run on a freshly-installed Linux system with no dependancies. This is the primary reason I switched from Common Lisp to Scheme in the first place.

What am I doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your program is in a-program.scm file:

```
csc -deploy a-program.scm
cd a-program/
chicken-install -deploy -p $PWD http-client
```

...et voilà!

**edit:** turns out that the proper answer to the problem posted is solved in this document: http://www.foldling.org/scheme.html#compiling-statically-linked-chicken-scheme-programs-with-extensions

Comment: Well, that's handy to know...and technically it **will** run on a fresh Linux install...but it's not an answer to my question, which was "how do I get everything in the one executable?" There are one hundred and ninety files in the $PWD after running `chicken-install`. That is, I feel, a tad excessive.

Comment: I don't mean to be mean but the question was "I need my executables to run on a freshly-installed Linux system with no dependancies. (...) What am I doing wrong, please?" ;) Anyway there is a tedious way claimed to build a single self-contained executable which might work for you: http://www.foldling.org/scheme.html#compiling-statically-linked-chicken-scheme-programs-with-extensions -- note that -deploy has already created the .o files in a-program/ -- however this might be harder than just csc -static a-program.o a-program/*.o -o aprog ... good luck!

Comment: ps maybe you could also try gambit-c, it worked for me but I didn't mess up with packages othern than than matcher and irregex...

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those out. But in my question, when I said "static linking", I kinda meant "everything in one executable". That's usually what the term means, in my experience.

Comment: Looks like the foldling.org way is the correct solution. If you'd like to make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Static linking of eggs is one of the things we want to improve with CHICKEN 5 as well by making it easier to do the right thing. Asking egg authors to take care of it didn't work out so well, as we noticed with CHICKEN 3; most authors neglected the static versions of their eggs because so few people use static linking.  Also, note that Gambit-C, while an excellent Scheme system in its own right, doesn't really _have_ an extension system, so the question is kind of moot, there.